# Android: SQLiteDatabase column doesn't exist error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've encountered an error with creating and loading my database for my program. I get an error of "no such column: responsible: , while compiling: 
SELECT id, name, responsible, priority
FROM tasks "

Can someone point out what I've done wrong. Thanks

```
public class TasksSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int VERSION = 1;
public static final String DB_NAME  = "tasks_db.sqlite";
public static final String TASKS_TABLE  = "tasks";
public static final String TASK_ID = "id";
public static final String TASK_NAME = "name";
public static final String TASK_COMPLETE  = "complete";
public static final String TASK_RESPONSIBLE  = "responsible";
public static final String TASK_PRIORITY  = "priority";

public TasksSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dropAndCreate(db);
}

protected void dropAndCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TASKS_TABLE + ";");
    createTables(db);
}

protected void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "create table " + TASKS_TABLE +" (" +
            TASK_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
            TASK_NAME + " text," +
            TASK_COMPLETE + " text," +
            TASK_RESPONSIBLE + " text" +
            TASK_PRIORITY + " integer" +
            ");"
        );
}
}
```

-

```
public class TaskManagerApplication extends Application {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ArrayList<Task> currentTasks;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    TasksSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new TasksSQLiteOpenHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (null == currentTasks) {
        loadTasks();
    }
}

private void loadTasks() {
    currentTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    Cursor tasksCursor = database.query(TASKS_TABLE, new String[] {
            TASK_ID, 
            TASK_NAME,
            TASK_RESPONSIBLE,
            TASK_PRIORITY,
            TASK_COMPLETE}, null, null, null, null, String.format("%s,%s", TASK_COMPLETE, TASK_NAME));
    tasksCursor.moveToFirst();
    Task t;
    if (! tasksCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            int id = tasksCursor.getInt(0);
            String name  = tasksCursor.getString(1);
            String priority  = tasksCursor.getString(2);
            String responsible = tasksCursor.getString(3);
            String boolValue = tasksCursor.getString(4);
            boolean complete = Boolean.parseBoolean(boolValue);
            t = new Task(name, priority, responsible);
            t.setId(id);
            t.setComplete(complete);
            currentTasks.add(t);
        } while (tasksCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    tasksCursor.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `CREATE TABLE`;

```
db.execSQL(
    "create table " + TASKS_TABLE +" (" +
    TASK_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
    TASK_NAME + " text," +
    TASK_COMPLETE + " text," +
    TASK_RESPONSIBLE + " text" + // <--- missing a comma
    TASK_PRIORITY + " integer" +
    ");"
);
```

Comment: My bad, I've fixed that, but still get the same problem.

Comment: clear application data and relaunch the app. This will cause the DDL scripts to run again which will create the tables again.

Comment: onCreate is only called if the SQLite database does not exist at all, not every time you open the application. You may need to force it to recreate the database after fixing the `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor typing error in your code. Corrected version :

```
db.execSQL(
    "create table " + TASKS_TABLE +" (" +
    TASK_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
    TASK_NAME + " text," +
    TASK_COMPLETE + " text," +
    TASK_RESPONSIBLE + " text," + 
    TASK_PRIORITY + " integer" +
   ");"
 );
```