# onUpgrade() method does not work properly

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

Im trying to call onUpgrade() to update my Table with few columns. however, when i run the app I get an error on the insert statement saying columns do not exist in this table (the columns i try to add in the onUpgrade(). I would really appreciate your help. 
Here's  my SQLite helper class: 
//UPDATED AND WORKING

```
public class TasksSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int VERSION = 3;
public static final String DB_NAME = "tasks_db.sqlite";
public static final String TASKS_TABLE = "tasks";
public static final String TASK_ID = "id";
public static final String TASK_NAME = "name";
public static final String TASK_RESPONSIBLE = "responsible";
public static final String TASK_PRIORITY = "priority";
public static final String TASK_DATETIME = "taskdatetime";


public TasksSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    createTables(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    Log.v("test",Integer.toString(oldVersion));
    Log.v("test", Integer.toString(newVersion));
switch(oldVersion){

case 1: db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+ TASKS_TABLE +" ADD COLUMN "+ TASK_RESPONSIBLE +" TEXT");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+ TASKS_TABLE +" ADD COLUMN "+ TASK_PRIORITY +" TEXT");
        Log.v("test","res + pri created");
        break;

case 2: db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+ TASKS_TABLE +" ADD COLUMN "+ TASK_DATETIME +" TEXT");
        Log.v("test","date created");
        break;
    }
}

    protected void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(
        "create table " + TASKS_TABLE+" (" + 
        TASK_ID + " integer primary key,"+ 
        TASK_NAME + " text"+ 
        ");"
        );
}
```

} 
and here's my Application class //UPDATED AND WORKING SOLUTION

```
    public class TaskManagerApplication extends Application {

private ArrayList<Task> currentTasks;
public SQLiteDatabase database;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    TasksSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new TasksSQLiteOpenHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (null == currentTasks) {
        loadTasks();
    }
}
private void loadTasks() {
    currentTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    Cursor tasksCursor = database.query(TASKS_TABLE, new String[] {TASK_ID, TASK_NAME,TASK_RESPONSIBLE,TASK_PRIORITY,TASK_DATETIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    tasksCursor.moveToFirst();
    Task t; 
    if (! tasksCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            long id = tasksCursor.getLong(0);
            String name  = tasksCursor.getString(1);
            String responsible  = tasksCursor.getString(2);
            String priority  = tasksCursor.getString(3);
            String datetime = tasksCursor.getString(4);
            t = new Task(name, priority, responsible, datetime);
            t.setId(id);
            currentTasks.add(t);
        } while (tasksCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    tasksCursor.close();
}

public void setCurrentTask(ArrayList<Task> currentTask) {
    this.currentTasks = currentTask; // set tasks in array
}

public ArrayList<Task> getCurrentTasks() {
    return currentTasks; //call back tasks
}

public void addTask(Task t) { // add new t of type Task
    assert(null != t); //check for null entries - avoid crashing
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TASK_NAME, t.getName());
    values.put(TASK_PRIORITY, t.getPriority());
    values.put(TASK_RESPONSIBLE, t.getResponsible());
    values.put(TASK_DATETIME, t.getDatetime());
    //Log.v("test", TASK_DATETIME);
    t.setId(database.insert(TASKS_TABLE, null, values));
    currentTasks.add(t);
}

public void remove(long id){
    //remove statement from table using where statement id
    database.delete(TASKS_TABLE, TASK_ID +" ="+ id, null);
}
```

}

also here's my logcat output

```
    08-28 16:30:41.170: I/Database(8931): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table      tasks has no column named datetime
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931): Error inserting datetime=Aug 28, 2012 4:30:41    PM responsible=Me priority=Medium name=go chi
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table   tasks has no column named datetime: , while compiling: INSERT INTO tasks(datetime,     responsible, priority, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):   at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):   at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1290)
    08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1710)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1567)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.id11078995.ghnaim.exercise1.TaskManagerApplication.addTask(TaskManagerApplication.java:64)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.id11078995.ghnaim.exercise1.AddTaskActivity.addTask(AddTaskActivity.java:59)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.id11078995.ghnaim.exercise1.AddTaskActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(AddTaskActivity.java:134)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at and roid.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2211)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:775)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:860)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
  08-28 16:30:41.190: E/Database(8931):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think datetime is a keyword in SQLite. For testing try to rename that one and execute your code again.

Furthermore, did you increase the number of that field?: public static final int VERSION = 3;

Comment: yes i did increase it.. at first it was 1, then i had to add Responsible and Priority columns. then i was asked to add DateTime column so i ended up with Version 3. It's a bit silly but thats what ive been asked to do in the exercise (uni course). 

Ill try rename the column and ill post my result

Comment: UPDATE // changed datetime to td and now i get an error on Responsible field. I think the Upgrade() is not updating the table and therefore these columns do not exist.

Comment: what does your log says for oldversion? It seems that the alter statement is not entered...

Comment: by the way. primary key columns already include the constraint "NOT NULL". Furthermore there is no need to set it autoincrement. The value will be automaticaly set one higher than the highest value of that column.

Comment: for oldVersion its 1 ...newVersion 2. how can i make it go from 1 >2>3 so it go through all the cases in my switch? thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no need to save the old data, I think that is a much easier way to update your database:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS);
  onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
  database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
```

Your final String DATABASE_CREATE includes all fields. Remove the "NOT NULL" and "autoincrement" in the primary key definition.

- clean your project
- uninstall your application
- reinstall it again.

For further information: [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Try this solution without losing the data:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        + newVersion);
  boolean lDateTimeExists = isColumnExisting(TASK_DATETIME);
  boolean lResponsible = isColumnExisting(TASK_RESPONSIBLE);
  boolean lPrio = isColumnExisting(TASK_PRIORITY);
  if (!lDateTime){
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+ TASKS_TABLE +" ADD COLUMN "+ TASK_DATETIME +" TEXT"); 
  }
  if (!lResponsible){
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+ TASKS_TABLE +" ADD COLUMN "+ TASK_RESPONSIBLE);       
  }
  if (!lPrio){
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+ TASKS_TABLE +" ADD COLUMN "+ TASK_PRIORITY +"   TEXT");       
  }
}

private boolean isColumnExisting(String pColumnName){
  try{
    db.execSQL("SELECT "+pColumnName+" from "+TABLE_TASKS);
  }catch(Exception e){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. everyone seems to point me to drop the table and create a new one. but unfortunately im not allowed to drop it. otherwise i would lose marks. Thanks for you help again. really appreciate ur efforts

Comment: testing now.. ill post my results soon

Comment: still same problem.. I honestly have no idea whats goin on now.. thank you all for your help. if anyone still keen to help maybe i can email you my entire project.. otherwise dont really waste your time. the whole thing is useless !!

Comment: then deinstall your app and rollback your db_version to 1

Comment: Problem SOLVED !! FINALLY.. UPDATED code attached above. 
again thank you all for your kind efforts. all your ideas helped me understand the problem and as a result worked on a combined solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is too obvious, but did you changed the database version? if not the onUpgrade() method would not work

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall and reinstall the application hopefully it will work.

Comment: tried that...didnt work. Thanks for your reply though. any other suggestions?

Comment: then must check you creating query.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131835/android-sqlitedatabase-column-doesnt-exist-error) check this

Comment: same solve method, but sometimes will need clear cache and data though..